# Dynamically reload swfObject function after jQuery load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, swfobject

I am trying to use jQuery's load() function to bring in some dynamic content (which I do not have much control over) and within that content, there are swfObject calls.

For some reason, jQuery does not execute these swfObject calls. It just shows the "No Flash" content. Is there any way to retrigger swfObject to get cracking again?

Comment: do you have a link to see this online?

Comment: I am a jerk! Absolutely. http://injection.jonathanminter.com - if you scroll down to the News Center and you hit "A/V" you will see where the Lamb of God news story is there is a giant box where a Flash player should be. I am using a basic load() function, nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

you're using two different containers for the content loaded below the tabs:

```
<div class="post-container news-posts"></div>
```

and

```
<div id="othernews" class="post-container"></div>
```

the first one is filled up with content initially. 
now, clicking on the 'A/V' tab doesn't flush this container, but instead simply hides it and loads the fresh content into the second container (#othernews).

now, your swfobject call is as follows:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/iFm9v0wvEnw&amp;color1=0x000000&amp;color2=0x333333&amp;rel=1&amp;fs=1&amp;showsearch=0&amp;showinfo=1&amp;hd=1", "vvq-8663-youtube-1", "604", "367", "9", vvqexpressinstall, vvqflashvars, vvqparams, vvqattributes);
```

as you can see, you're trying to load the swf into an element with id `vvq-8663-youtube-1` here, but such an element is already existing in the dom, inside the first container (.news-posts), but after the ajax load it's available in the second container, too. you're certainly aware that having two elements with the same id is not allowed, and breaks your swf insertion.

i'd recommend using one single container to hold the content of your tabs. not only this will solve your swfobject troubles, but also free browser resources.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...
I can load (and unload) one or more swf on another swf (the Master Swf) with 
a simple comunication beetween differents swf with the **localConnection** function.
then you can use the simple internal loader as the MovieClipLoader or whatever u need.

then, if I need it, I can comunicate Flash with javscript with **ExternalInterface**.
With this two ways, I dont need (at all) go through the swfObject, and that is so good

;)